# how to get my count repeatidly decrease by 1 every day on MongoDB document

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

i have a mongodb document which looks like the following:

```
{
  id: "someId"
  useEmail: "someEmail"
  membershipDaysLeft: 30
}
```

i want the membershipDaysLeft document to decrease by 1 every day until it reaches 0. what would be the best optimal way to do it? using React, node.js and Mongoose (MongoDB)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way would be to store the date when the membership ends like:

```
{
  _id: "someId",
  email: "email",
  memberUntil: "2023-03-27T14:28:01+00:00"
}
```

Then you can calculate days until that date using Javascript.

---

If you still want to keep the count of days and decrement it every day, then you can run a function ([Scheduled cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) might be useful) every midnight to decrement all those documents.

```
// trigger this function everyday

db.collection.updateOne(
   { },
   { $inc: { membershipDaysLeft: -1 } }
)
```